# Making a chat application with parse.com and choosing recipients

Tags: android, parse-platform

I've been stuck on this for a couple of days now. I made a chat application using parse.com with this tutorial at https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Building-Simple-Chat-Client-with-Parse **How do I make it so that the user can select a recipient (another parseUser)?** I want to make it so that the app will be one on one chatting or as a group chat. Right now the app doesn't have a "choose a recipient" option so the chats are coming in to every parseUser.

Comment: @Aster I'm still new to parse and android. I've looked at parse's docs on their website and I still can't figure out on where to start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add to the Message.java:

```
...

public String getReceiverId() {
    return getString("receiverId");
}

public void setReceiverId(String receiverId) {
    put("receiverId", receiverId);
}

...
```

Then in the ChatActivity.java you need to send the id of the friend you want to send a message to. I use intent to pass it through on clicking on a friend in a listview.

```
private static String sFriendsId;
....

Intent callingIntent = getIntent();
sFriendsId = callingIntent.getExtras().getString("friendsObjectId");
```

Then under the  setupMessagePosting() method you need to set the receiver id:

```
   // When send button is clicked, create message object on Parse
    btSend.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String body = etMessage.getText().toString();
            // Use Message model to create new messages now
            Message message = new Message();
            message.setUserId(sUserId);
            message.setReceiverId(sFriendsId);
            message.setBody(body);
            message.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
                @Override
                public void done(ParseException e) {
                    receiveMessage();
                }
            });
            etMessage.setText("");
        }
    });
```

Lastly add to the receiveMessage() method:

```
...
    // Sent Messages Query
    ParseQuery<Message> sentMessagesQuery = ParseQuery.getQuery(Message.class);
    sentMessagesQuery.whereEqualTo("userId", sUserId);
    sentMessagesQuery.whereEqualTo("receiverId", sFriendsId);

    // Receiver Messages Query
    ParseQuery<Message> receiveMessagesQuery = ParseQuery.getQuery(Message.class);
    receiveMessagesQuery.whereEqualTo("userId", sFriendsId);
    receiveMessagesQuery.whereEqualTo("receiverId", sUserId); //receiver is me (current user)

    // Combine the queries
    List<ParseQuery<Message>> queries = new ArrayList<>();
    queries.add(sentMessagesQuery);
    queries.add(receiveMessagesQuery);

    // Get the messages
    ParseQuery<Message> mainQuery = ParseQuery.or(queries);
    // Configure limit and sort order
    mainQuery.setLimit(MAX_CHAT_MESSAGES_TO_SHOW);
    mainQuery.orderByAscending("createdAt");

    mainQuery.findInBackground(new FindCallback<Message>() {
....
```

Comment: thanks for that pointer, i did like to ask, what if i want to add Push notification for every message being sent and received.

Answer (score 0):

To send the id of the friend you want to send a message to. You must use intent to pass it through on clicking on a friend in a listview.
Just like this:

```
userListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MessageListActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("username", usersId.get(position));
            Log.i("user", users.get(position));
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

Query:

```
ParseQuery<ParseUser> query = ParseUser.getQuery();
    query.whereNotEqualTo("username", ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getUsername());
    query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseUser>() {
        @Override
        public void done(List<ParseUser> objects, ParseException e) {
            if(e==null){
                if(objects.size() >0){
                    for(ParseUser user : objects){
                        users.add(user.getUsername());
                        usersId.add(user.getObjectId());
                    }
                    arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            }
        }
    });
```